# Выполнение события при условии if

Tags: jquery, rangeslider

Всем отличного настроения!

Пытаюсь выполнить событие, если value у элемента input=text достигло необходимого значения:

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        value:5000,
        min: 0,
        max: 300000,
        step: 5000,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
        }
    });
    var strAmountValue = $('#amount').attr("value");
    if (strAmountValue === 300000) {
        alert("Добро пожаловать!");
    }
} );
```

```css
.form .range.budget label {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.form .range.budget .ui-slider {
    height: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    background-color: #111;
}
.form .range.budget .ui-slider-handle {
    left: 2%;
    background: #ffd218;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -9px;
    border: 1px solid #222;
}
#amount.budget {
    color: #ef0832;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Roboto";

}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="form">
  <div class="form_group range budget">
      <p>
          <label for="amount">Бюджет:</label>
          <input type="text" id="amount" class="budget_value" readonly>
      </p>
      <div id="slider"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

но событие не срабатывает, хотя я по идее в переменной получил через attr("value") значение элемента и задал условие. Подскажите что не так делаю?

Comment: Вам нужно эту проверку делать в коллбеке который возникает при изменении значения, поищите такой в документации.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    if (ui.value == 30000) {
        alert('Привет!');
    }
    $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку!